# Duplicate symbols in monotouch library and some 3rd party library I use

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, static-libraries

I'm working on an iPhone app with Monotouch. In my app, I have to use a static library provided by 3rd party. This library is for Xcode and written in Objective-C. I bound it with Monotouch using Binding Project Template. When I add the resulting `dll` to my project it compiles fine, but when I use a class from the library it fails to compile with the following error:

```
Duplicate symbol _DeleteCriticalSection
```

So what can I do? Is there any way to remove the conflict?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar things inside FAT libraries where some files were duplicated, leading to duplicate objects. You can try to see if this is the same issue, e.g. if your library is named `mystaticlibrary.a`

```
$ nm mystaticlibrary.a | grep DeleteCriticalSection
```

Now it can be normal to have the symbol multiple times if you have a FAT library (more than one architecture). To see if that's the case do:

```
$ file mystaticlibrary.a
```

You should have the symbol for each architecture. If you see more symbols (e.g. 3x `DeleteCriticalSection` but only 2 arch) then you have a similar issue.

The fix (if it's the same issue) was to split the FAT library (`lipo` tool), then each architecture specific library, then re-merge everything (arch then FAT).

Your best bet might be to contact your library vendor and ask him for a fixed library (something was likely wrong in the build process). Give them the above command output and they'll likely find out what went wrong.